# Firebase functions update document / sendgrid

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have this function of Firebase Firestore, every time a new document is created in the collection `pagos` I am sending a transactional email through Sendgrid with the data of this new document created. It works well.

My question is how do I do the same function, that is, to send said email but only when the document is updated with a certain field (for example `dataPago`) Can it be done?

Here my function when creating a document:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const SENDGRID_API_KEY = functions.config().sendgrid.key

const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(SENDGRID_API_KEY);

exports.pagoRealizado = functions.firestore
  .document('pagos/{pagoId}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
     const pagoId = context.params.pagoId;
     const db = admin.firestore()
     return db.collection('pagos').doc(pagoId)
       .get()
       .then(doc => {
          const pago = doc.data();
          const msg = {
            from: 'xxx@gmail.com',
            to: 'xxx@xxx.com',
            templateId: 'd-3473a9cc588245b7b2a6633f05dafdd8',
            substitutionWrappers: ['{{', '}}'],
            dynamic_template_data: {
               nombre: pago.dataCliente.nombre,
               }
          };
            return sgMail.send(msg)
          })
          .then(() => console.log('email enviado!'))
          .catch(err => console.log(err))
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an onCreate trigger, you can use an onUpdate trigger.  This will fire whenever a matched document is changed in some way, but not created or deleted.  You can read more about each kind of Firestore trigger in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events).

You can't set up a trigger on specific field in a document.  The trigger will fire when any field in the document changes in any way.  You will have to check the before and after states of the document snapshots delivered to the function in order to figure out if it's a change you want to act on.  Again, the documentation talks about this in more detail.